# Rspec how to stub an object created within a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am in the process of refactoring a bloated controller that serves a polymorphic model for carousels. I am trying to build a class method that handles finding and returning the item that is carouselable.

In my RSPEC tests I want to stub the method, 'is_something?' on the venue that is found as a result of the params.

```
  def self.find_carouselable(params)
    .......
    elsif params[:venue_id].present?
      venue=Venue.friendly.find(params[:venue_id])
      if venue.is_something? 
        do this 
      else
        do that
      end
    end
  end
```

I cant work out how to stub an object that is created as a result of the inputted data - I am not sure if this is called stubbing or mocking?

```
  context "carouselable is a venue" do 
    before do 
      allow(the_venue).to receive(:is_something?).and_return(true)
    end

    it "returns the instance of the carouselable object" do 
      expect(CopperBoxCarouselItem.find_carouselable(venue_params)).to eq the_venue
    end
   end
```

many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to stub the Venue bit, like so

```
      before do 
        allow(Venue).to receive(:friendly).and_return(some_venues)
        allow(some_venues).to receive(:find).and_return(venue)
        allow(venue).to receive(:is_something?).and_return(true)
      end
```

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to do:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Venue).to receive(:is_something?).and_return(true)
```

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/message-expectations/allow-a-message-on-any-instance-of-a-class